Vscode extension Continue.dev cannot index a new Doc
Anyone succeeded in indexing a custom doc using Continue.dev vscode extension?
I tried to follow the doc Indexing Your Own Documentation
my embeddingsProvider is as follow
{
  "embeddingsProvider": [
    {
      "provider": "openai",
      "model": "text-embedding-3-large",
      "apiKey": "[API_KEY]"
    }
  ]
}

I add a new doc entry as follow
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "title": "Pandas",
      "startUrl": "https://pandas.pydata.org/docs",
      "rootUrl": "https://pandas.pydata.org/docs",
      "faviconUrl": "https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/_static/favicon.ico"
    }
  ]
}

but In Developer Tools console I get Error chunking article:  TypeError: embeddingsProvider.embed is not a function
the full log is
[Extension Host] Crawl completed
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Creating embeddings for 329 articles
329
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Error chunking article:  TypeError: embeddingsProvider.embed is not a function
    at _DocsService.indexAndAdd (c:\Users\salticidae\.vscode\extensions\continue.continue-0.9.215-win32-x64\out\extension.js:448881:64)
    at indexAndAdd.next (<anonymous>)
    at _DocsService.syncConfigAndSqlite (c:\Users\salticidae\.vscode\extensions\continue.continue-0.9.215-win32-x64\out\extension.js:449009:36)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async c:\Users\salticidae\.vscode\extensions\continue.continue-0.9.215-win32-x64\out\extension.js:448981:13
log.ts:439   ERR [Extension Host] No embeddings were created for site: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs
 Num chunks: 4009
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] No embeddings were created for site: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs
 Num chunks: 4009

anyone had better luck?
Maybe using their recommended embeddingsProvider Voyage AI or Ollama?

Your question looks similar to https://github.com/continuedev/continue/issues/2022

Or looks like https://github.com/continuedev/continue/issues/2527. Always check-out issues from repository before posting new question.

thanks for reviewing my question :) the second is actually mine.

Oh, didn't noticed it is yours. I am glad you solved your bug

I decided to reinstall vscode. It was a quite old installation that was carried over on 2 different laptops. After I reinstallation the error was gone.
If you decide to do the same, before uninstalling, to clean the Synced Data otherwise the old bunch of deprecated extensions will comeback the first time you login in your clean install:
F1 > Show Synced Data > [three dot] > Clear Data in Cloud...
The Doc crawler is limited though, and doesn't work for all websites (sphinx generated doc never works for me)

You don't believe me but seems actually it not worked properly in last few releases. On both release and pre-release versions. I am filled the issue, check if it is related to your casse: https://github.com/continuedev/continue/issues/2977
